# Not locally compact why?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

let   $E=\mathcal{C}([0,\pi],\mathbb{R})$ and $$d(f,g)=\sqrt{\int_0^{\pi} (f(x)-g(x))^2 dx}, ~\forall f,g\in E$$

How to prove that $E$ is not locally compact ?

- i proved that $f_n(x)=\sin(nx), n\in \mathbb{N}$ is not a Cauchy sequence in $(E,d)$ so it has no adherent value

i proved also that $d(0,f_n)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$

but i don't know how i can use it ?

thank you

Comment: The metric is induced by the L2-norm, so if E was locally compact, it would be finite dimensional by Riesz's lemma. Contradiction.

Comment: @tetsuzan i must only use the preceding questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use what you have done to show that every neighborhood of $0$ contains a sequence with no convergent subsequence. Hence $0$ cannot have a compact neighborhood. (In metric spaces, compactness is equivalent to sequential compactness.) Indeed, let $\epsilon > 0$. We have $d(0,\frac{\epsilon}{2}f_n) = \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon^2 \pi}{8}} = \epsilon\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}} < \epsilon$, so each $\frac{\epsilon}{2}f_n$ belongs to the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $0$. Moreover, whenever $n \neq m$ we have $d(\frac{\epsilon}{2}f_n,\frac{\epsilon}{2}f_m) = \frac{\epsilon}{2}\sqrt\pi$. Thus the sequence $(\frac{\epsilon}{2}f_n)_{n \geq 1}$ belongs to the open ball yet admits no convergent subsequence.

Comment: i don't understand your proof, if i suppose that $E$ is localy compact, then $0$ has a ngbh compact , how to continue how to use f_n

Comment: Dear @Vrouvrou, this is not a proof by contradiction, so we don't want to suppose that $E$ is locally compact. To prove that $E$ is *not* locally compact, we show that $0$ has *no* compact neighborhood.

Comment: @Vrouvrou Or, if you want to turn the argument into a proof by contradiction: suppose $E$ is locally compact, then $0$ has a compact neighborhood. As a neighborhood, it contains an open ball of some radius $\epsilon$ centered at $0$. This open ball (and hence also the compact neighborhood) contains a sequence $(\frac{\epsilon}{2}f_n)$ with no convergent subsequence. Contradiction.

Comment: why it must contains $(\frac{\epsilon}{2}f_n)$ ? Is it because 0 is a limite so by definition of the limitis there exists n_0 , from n_0 $(\frac{\epsilon}{2}f_n)$ is in the ngbh of 0 ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou It contains that sequence because the distance between each sequence element and $0$ is strictly smaller than $\epsilon$. This means precisely that the sequence elements all belong to the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $0$.

Comment: We can't say that $(\frac{\epsilon}{2}f_n)$ converge to 0 in $(E,d)$ ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou No. We have shown that the distance between any two distinct sequence elements is always constant (equal to $\frac{\epsilon}{2}\sqrt\pi$), so the sequence (or any of its subsequences) cannot possibly converge to anything.

Comment: Please if (f_n) is not a Cauchy sequence then it has no adherent value ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou The sequence $(-1)^n$ in $\mathbb{R}$ isn't Cauchy but it has two adherent values.

Comment: So please how to prove that $(f_n)$  has no adherent values

Comment: @Vrouvrou We have shown that the sequence admits no convergent subsequence. This is equivalent to the fact that the sequence has no adherent values.

Comment: how to see that $(f_n)$ has no convergent subsequence please what is the definition ?